Postfix Sender and Recipient Restriction
I am trying to add additional security from my postfix relay server we have an ACL whitelisting file, i would like to add the feature that can block by sender and recipient address even the IP is already in the ACL
#smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access, reject

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_access reject

I have tried to command above but it doesn't work
My goal is to have the IPs whitelisted but restrict some senders and recipient
